# How to execute a Python file in Notepadqq for Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++

I'm trying to run a python script using Notepadqq in Ubuntu, but when I try running my script by going to the Run command it oop up a windows that says
Special Placeholders

[image]

with the options to save or OK and cancel. See image

Answer (score 0):

I think like that:

```
/usr/bin/python3 %path%
```

Comment: Good suggestions, still the output of the code is not visible with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I use two "Run" shortcuts.

This runs the code and holds the xterm open so I can see the output. Handy if there's an error.

```
/usr/bin/xterm -hold -e /usr/bin/python3 %path%
```

And to auto close the xterm.

```
/usr/bin/xterm -e /usr/bin/python3 %path%
```

Make sure to save your file because this works with the file on the disk at `%path%`

Also you can change `/usr/bin/xterm` to point to whatever term you like.

Answer (score 0):

This window allows you to have several previously configured commands. For example, you can create one command to execute the default python2.7 (/usr/bin/python2.7), another one to execute with python3 (/usr/bin/python3), or perhaps a specific virtual environment python (let's say /home/py3env/bin/python).

Natively, notepadqq won't know you want to execute it with python. At the blank space, write the following command (edit python path if needed):

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 %path%'
```

After that, click the "Save" button. You will be asked to enter a name for the command (e.g. "run default python3"). After this, you can run your python scripts by clicking on you named command.

If you need the terminal to be kept open after the command is executed, you can edit your terminal preferences. Open a terminal and follow this path:
(edit -> preferences -> go to your profile -> "Command" tab -> When commands exits -> Hold the terminal open)

[gnome-terminal-preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evYfU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Running the code depends on the console you want to use. Since the question asks for a Ubuntu solution I'd suggest gnome-terminal.

```
gnome-terminal -e "python3 %path%"
```

Here's a screenshot and sample code for clarity. The last line `input()` prevents the window from closing so the user can view the output. I've tried this solution with Ubuntu 20.04.

[image]